# Refresh a table after a selection of records

Tags: forms

I want to write a module with a textfield, a submit button and a table.
The starting page displays an empty textfield, the button and the table that shows all the records.
When the user writes something in the textfield, and clicks the button, the web page refreshes itself; then the table should contain only the records with the same Name Field as the string that the user wrote. Unfortunately, it doesn't works: The new page displays the same records shown before, even if the query produced a correct table.

This is the code I use.

```
function prova_db_advanced_list($form, &$form_state) {

  $form = array();

  $form['textfield_input'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t("Compilare i campi in base alla ricerca che si desidera effettuare.")
  );

  $form['textfield_input']['nome'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Inserisci un nome'),
    '#size' => 15,
  );
  $form['textfield_input']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t("Find"),
  );

  $select = db_select('persone_prova_db', 'p');

  // Join the users table, so we can get the entry creator's username.
  $select->join('indirizzi_prova_db', 'i', 'p.residenza = i.id');

  // Select these specific fields for the output.
  $select->addField('p', 'id');
  $select->addField('p', 'cognome');
  $select->addField('p', 'nome');
  $select->addField('p', 'codice_fiscale');
  $select->addField('i', 'id');
  $select->addField('i', 'via_piazza');
  $select->addField('i', 'civico');
  $select->addField('i', 'comune');
  $select->addField('i', 'provincia');

  // Make sure we only get items 0-49, for scalability reasons.
  $select->range(0, 50);

  // Get all entries in the prova_db table.
  $entries = $select->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if (!empty($entries)) {
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {

      // Sanitize the data before handing it off to the theme layer.
      $rows[] = array_map('check_plain', $entry);
    }

    // Make a table for them.
    $header = array(t('Id Persona'), t('Cognome'), t('Nome'), t('Codice Fiscale'),
                t('Id Indirizzo'), t('Via/Piazza'), t('Num. Civico'), t('Comune'), t('Provincia'));
  }else {     
    drupal_set_message(t('No entries meet the filter criteria.'));
  }

  $form['table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('Empty Rows')
  );     
 return $form;
 }
 function prova_db_advanced_list_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t("Tabella"));
  drupal_set_message(t("Il nome inserito è @name_to_find",  array('@name_to_find'=>$form_state['values']['nome'])));
  $name_to_find = $form_state['values']['nome'];
  $select = db_select('persone_prova_db', 'p');

  // Join the users table, so we can get the entry creator's username.
  $select->join('indirizzi_prova_db', 'i', 'p.residenza = i.id');

  // Select these specific fields for the output.
  $select->addField('p', 'id');
  $select->addField('p', 'cognome');
  $select->addField('p', 'nome');
  $select->addField('p', 'codice_fiscale');
  $select->addField('i', 'id');
  $select->addField('i', 'via_piazza');
  $select->addField('i', 'civico');
  $select->addField('i', 'comune');
  $select->addField('i', 'provincia');
  $select->condition('p.nome', $name_to_find);

  // Make sure we only get items 0-49, for scalability reasons.
  $select->range(0, 50);

  // Get all entries in the prova_db table.
  $entries = $select->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if (!empty($entries)) {
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {   
      // Sanitize the data before handing it off to the theme layer.
      $rows[] = array_map('check_plain', $entry);
    }
    drupal_set_message(t("Table: @rows", array('@rows' => $rows)));
    $form['table']= array('#type' => 'value', '#rows' => $rows);
      $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  }else {     
    drupal_set_message(t('No entries meet the filter criteria'));
  } 
}
```

I don't understand where I'm wrong. I searched if someone else have the same trouble, but I haven't found the way to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: As side note, the string passed to `t()` needs to contain English words, as the translation is done from English to the language currently for the site.

Answer (score 1):

`$form` is an array that is not passed as reference to the form submission handler; therefore, any change done to `$form` from the submission handler is local to the form submission handler. This is similar to what happens with the following code.

```
$array = array('a' => 10);
$array = update_array($array);
check_array($array);

function update_array($array) {
  return $array + array('b' => 20);
}

function check array($array) {
  $array['b'] = 30;
}
```

After that code is executed, `$array['b']` is still equal to 20.

The only parameter that is passed by reference is `$form_state`. If you want to pass a value back to the form builder, from the form submission handler, or the form validation handler, you need to use `$form_state`, which mean the form submission hander should use code similar to the following one.

```
$form_state['table_rows'] = $rows;
```

The form builder should use the following code.

```
if (!empty($form_state['table_rows']) {
  $rows = $form_state['table_rows'];
}
else {
  // Execute the query that gets every row in the database table.
  // Assign the found rows to $rows.
}

$form['table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#empty' => t('Empty Rows')
);
```

The values you are placing in `$rows` is wrong. What you are using in an array similar to the following one.

```
array(
  'column 1 name' => 'column 1 value',
  'column 2 name' => 'column 2 value',
)
```

The array [theme_table()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) is expecting is one of the following.

```
  array(
    'column 1 value', 'column 1 value', 'column 2 value'
  )
```

```
 array(
    'data' => array('column 1 value', array('data' => 'column 2 value', 'colspan' => 2)), 'class' => array('column-class')
  )
```

Supposing the changes to the content of `$form` would be propagated externally to the form submission handler, the code for the form builder is writing `$form['table'] without first checking if`$form['table']`is set; this would mean losing the value for`$form['table']` set from the form submission handler.